# What is the difference between using the 'X -config' command and the 'startx' command

Tags: xorg, x-windows

I get very different results when using

```
X -config /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

than just plain

```
startx
```

Namely, that the 1st command just gives me a black screen, while startx actually shows some X windows.

Answer (score 4):

As the startx man page says,

> **startx - initialize an X session** 
>          The startx script is a front end to xinit that provides a somewhat
>   nicer user interface for running
>          a single session of the X Window System.  It is often run with
>   no arguments.

The `X` command runs the X server. `startx` does that and also initializes the session, i.e. runs what is specified in the configuration files, typically the windowing environment, xterm etc.

> To determine the client to run, startx first looks for a file called
>   .xinitrc in  the  user’s  home
>    directory.  If that is not found, it uses the file xinitrc in the
>   xinit library directory.

To illuminate further, startx uses these files:

```
   $(HOME)/.xinitrc         Client  to  run.  Typically a shell script which runs many programs in the
                            background.

   $(HOME)/.xserverrc       Server to run.  The default is X.

   /usr/lib/X11/xinit/xinitrc
                            Client to run if the user has no .xinitrc file.

   /usr/lib/X11/xinit/xserverrc
                            Server to run if the user has no .xserverrc file.
```

Answer (score 0):

the startx uses the files listed in the other reply,while the "-config" option uses a user-specified configuration file

Comment: The -config option specifies the X server configuration. It is not equivalent to an xinitrc or xserverrc file.